# Finding a regular grammar for the language L

Tags: regex, automata, formal-languages

I know a solution for following question using 4 variables including start variable but not less than 4. Is there a solution using less than 4 variables?

**Find a regular grammar for the language L = {a^n * b^m : n,m>=0, n + m is odd} using less than 4 variables including S.**

Comment: I found one but I'm not sure if this one covers every possibilities.

S -> aaS | bB | aA , 
A -> bbA | λ , 
B -> bbB | λ

Answer (score 1):

You've provided a correct suggestion in comments, but you can eliminate one non-terminal (variable), so that it becomes:

→ 
       → 
       →

→ 
       → ε

This says that an input is accepted if and only when it consists of an even number of , followed by either one  or one , followed by an even number of .

NB: I used the more common practice to use ε for representing the empty string.

In the more compact regex syntax this would be:

```
(aa)*[ab](bb)*
```

Comment: Now I see it clear. Thank you!